# What do you call an office separated into individual spaces?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, image-identification

I'm writing a paper and I have to describe what a certain work environment looks like. However, I don't know the proper term for this type of office layout. Surely you don't just call it a block office. I searched a lot, but wasn't able to find anything on this.

[image: office workers on a floor; standing, wandering around, some seated at their desks, the space is divided into partitions]

Comment: http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0151804

Comment: This is a [*cubicle sea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubicle#Sea_of_cubicles), one kind of [open plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_plan) arrangement (though to my mind *open plan* usually suggests no dividers at all).

Comment: @Benyamin: if that image is sourced from somewhere (like Shutterstock, perhaps), it must be attributed and their licence must allow it to be used here with Stack Exchange's CC-BY-SA licence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an open space with  [cubicle setting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubicle):

> - ***Тhe cubicle is a partially enclosed workspace in an office which is separated from neighboring workspaces by partitions that are usually 5–6 feet (1.5–1.8 m) tall.***
> - ***Its purpose is to isolate office workers and managers from the sights and noises of an open workspace so that they may concentrate with fewer distractions.***
> - Cubicles are composed of modular elements such as walls, work surfaces, overhead bins, drawers, and shelving, which can be configured depending on the user's needs.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Hmm. Having to correct silly downvotes now.

Comment: Informal: Cube Farm. https://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/inlineimage/630x0/dilbert-cube-farm_34500.gif

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different take than Mike's

**Cubalcatraz** (or Cubicaltraz as UD has it).

> Cubicaltraz is a reference to the prizon like atmosphere that pervades the business office and cubicalvilles everywhere. A combination of Alcatraz and cubical.

Urban Dictionary "cubicaltraz"

Also consider **deskicle**

> Meaning : n. A half-desk, half cubicle workspace designed to foster a collaborative environment and remove privacy via atypically lower walls. Commonly appear in groups.
>
> Example : He was walking by my deskicle and totally caught me
>   slacking.

AZdictionary "deskicle".

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an attractive **Open Plan** office, enhanced as it is with a plant and lots of natural light.

Comment: If you like this sort of office it's 'open plan'; if you don't it's a 'cubicle zoo'.

Comment: An "open plan" office would be without the partitions.